# App Bar button on the right side of the screen Windows 8 metro style apps

Tags: windows-8

I am developing the metro style windows 8 app using html,javascript and css.

I am using app bar at bottom in my application.Following is the html code.

```
<div id="appbarbottom" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{layout:'custom',placement:'bottom'}">
    <button id="playerBut" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{section:'global',label:'Player', icon:'placeholder',type:'flyout',flyout:sportsFlyout}" type="button"></button>

</div>
```

I rad the official document it said that `section:'global'` will make the button to the right side. I did that but it has no effect.

I had tried with `section:'selection'`  but still button remains on the left side

I have searched for alternative solution but everyone says the same thing so how can I achieve my goal.Please give me helpful hand.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had removed  `'layout:custom'` from `data-win-options="{layout:'custom',placement:'bottom'}`

of the `data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar"`  and it solved my problem.

I almost wasted 4 hours on this.

I hope this will help others.

Thanks.